# Detect with php if files is being uploaded, or is open

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that opens a local directory in order to copy and process some files. But these files may be incomplete, because they are being uploaded by a slow FTP process, and I do not want to copy or process any files which have not been completely uploaded yet.

Is is possible in PHP to find out if a file is still being copied (that is, read from), or written to?

I need my script to process only those files that have been completely uploaded.

The ftp process now, upload files in parallel, and it take more than 1 second for each filesize to change, so this trick is not working for me now, any other method suggests

Answer (score 4):

Do you have script control over the FTP process? If so, have the script that's doing the uploading upload a [FILENAME].complete file (blank text file) after the primary upload completes, so the processing script knows that the file is complete if there's a matching *.complete file there also.

Comment: this is the problem, i don't have the control of the upload script, i have only one folder where i can find my files to process at any time, so i have to detect if files are completed or not

Answer (score 3):

+1 to @MidnightLightning for his excellent suggestion. If you don't have control over the process you have a couple of options:

If you know what the final size of the file should be then use `filesize()` to compare the current size to the known size. Keep checking until they match.

If you don't know what the final size should be it gets a little trickier. You could use `filesize()` to check the size of the file, wait a second or two and check it again. If the size hasn't changed then the upload should be complete. The problem with the second method is if your file upload stalls for whatever reason it could give you a false positive. So the time to wait is key.

Comment: +1; I was going to suggest this as well, if you don't have control of the files.

Comment: I have also tried those solution, and they works for sometimes, but the ftp process now, upload files in parallel, and it take more than 1 second for filesize to change, so this trick is not working for me now, any other method suggests?

Comment: @albanx - I think your only option in that case would be to increase the wait time. Or check several times before you decide the upload has stopped

Comment: Is that what I have done for the moment, I have put the wait time at 3 seconds, but I think that this solution could give problems :(( any way for imediate resposes thanks to all

Comment: Is a 3-second wait time really too long? Is the processing script one that a user is watching run, or is it an automated process? It sounds like the ideal setup would be to have the PHP script run once a minute, recording file sizes, and keeping track of changes. Any file that doesn't change over three runs gets processed and flagged as done. Or is this a script users are accessing through a web interface?

Comment: No, the php script runs every 3 minutues, at every run it search the files and if the size of this files does not change every 3 seconds then it process them. 1 minute(60 sec) is a very long time, if i make my process wait 1 minutes for each file to filesize change, and if i have 20 files in my ftp, that takes each 10 seconds to be uploaded than my process will take 60x20x10=1200 seconds to finish the processing, too long time, The only way is to write the scrit in C++ or VB.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify what kind of OS you're on, but if it's a Unix-type box, you should have `fuser` and/or `lsof` available. fuser will report on who's using a particular file, and lsof will list all open files (including sockets, fifos, .so's, etc...). Either of those could most likely be used to monitor your directory.

On the windows end, there's a few free tools from Sysinternals that do the same thing. [`handle`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) might do the trick

Comment: sorry, unfortunately i have windows server 2008