# Get PHP to wait until a file is done transferring before moving it

Tags: php, ibm-midrange

I have a PHP script that moves files out of a specific folder on the server(an IBM AS400). The problem I am running into is that sometimes the script runs while the file is still in the process of being moved in to the folder.

Poor logic on my part assumed that if a file was "in use" that PHP wouldn't attempt to move it but it does which results in a corrupted file.

I thought I could do this:

```
$oldModifyTime = filemtime('thefile.pdf');
sleep(2);
if($oldModifyTime === filemtime('thefile.pdf'){
  rename('thefile.pdf','/folder2/thefile.pdf');
}
```

But the filemtime functions come up with the same value even while the file is being written. I have also tried fileatime with the same results.

If I do Right Click->Properties in Windows the Modified Date and Access Date are constantly changing as the file is being written.

Any ideas how to determine if a file is finished transferring before doing anything to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP manual entry for [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php):

**Note:** The results of this function are cached. See [`clearstatcache()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) for more details.

---

I would also suggest that 2 seconds is a bit short to detect whether the file transfer is complete due to network congestion, buffering, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Transfer it as a temporary name or to a different folder, then rename/copy it to the correct folder after the transfer is complete.

Comment: The initial file is coming from an end user saving a file into the folder so I can't automatically "rename/copy to the correct folder" without doing it on the server end and running into the same problem.

Comment: This really is the best solution.  If it's a manual process, you might need to educate your user and adjust your script.  For example, you could ignore all files that ended in .tmp and instruct your user to upload using a .tmp, then rename after upload.

Comment: if even that isn't possible, then take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4693168/608781